# How do you get the users on FB who shared a specific link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

Is there a way to do this?

I've read about /sharedposts but I'm not sure how to get the Object ID of a link. I tried using FQL to get the ID like:

`/fql?q=SELECT id, url  FROM object_url  WHERE url='http://example.com'`

OR even the comments_fbid from link_stat

These two returns an ID but when I do

`/1234567890/sharedposts`

It returns an empty array even though I've already shared the URL a couple of times.

Is this just not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be the privacy settings of the posts:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/sharedposts#readperms says concerning permissions that

> A user access token with read_stream permission, for someone who is able to view the post after privacy settings are taken into account.